# Error executing sqlite query

Tags: android, android-sqlite

**P.S this query is giving sqlite exception **

```
Cursor cur= db.rawQuery("SELECT " + Constants.Qt_um_stock_items_qty_BAL_DATE + " AS_ON_DT, " + " (IFNULL ( " + Constants.Qt_um_stock_items_qty_IN_QTY +", 0)-IFNULL (" 
                                         +Constants.Qt_um_stock_items_qty_OUT_QTY +", 0)) AS CL_QTY,"+  "(SELECT " + Constants.Stock_ItemsCODE + " || '-' || " 
                                         + Constants.Stock_ItemsNAME + " FROM " + Constants.Qm_Stock_Items_TABLE + " WHERE " + Constants.Stock_ItemsID + " = " 
                                         + Constants.Qt_um_stock_items_qty_STOCK_ITEM_ID+") AS ITEM," + "(SELECT " + Constants.UnitCODE + "|| '-' ||" 
                                         + Constants.UnitNAME + " FROM " + Constants. Qm_Unit_TABLE + " WHERE " + Constants.UnitID + " = " 
                                         + Constants.Qt_um_stock_items_qty_BASE_UNIT_ID+" ) AS UNIT FROM " + Constants.Qt_um_stock_items_qty_table +" WHERE "
                                         + Constants. Qt_um_stock_items_qty_STOCK_CENTRE_ID+"=?" + " AND " + Constants. Qt_um_stock_items_qty_STOCK_ITEM_ID 
                                         + " IN " + "=?",new String[] {StockCenterId, StockItemId});
```

**Log Cat**

```
10-17 06:02:50.042: E/SQLiteLog(3608): (1) near "=": syntax error
10-17 06:02:50.054: D/AndroidRuntime(3608): Shutting down VM
10-17 06:02:50.054: W/dalvikvm(3608): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT BAL_DATE AS_ON_DT,  (IFNULL ( IN_QTY, 0)-IFNULL (OUT_QTY, 0)) AS CL_QTY,(SELECT CODE || '-' || NAME FROM qm_um_stock_items WHERE ID = STOCK_ITEM_ID) AS ITEM,(SELECT CODE|| '-' ||NAME FROM qm_um_unit WHERE ID = BASE_UNIT_ID ) AS UNIT FROM Qt_um_stock_items_qty WHERE STOCK_CENTER_ID =? AND STOCK_ITEM_ID IN (=?)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at com.manacle.umma.activity.HeaderDb.getStockbal(HeaderDb.java:3901)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at com.manacle.umma.activity.StockBalrep$4.onClick(StockBalrep.java:185)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-17 06:02:50.114: E/AndroidRuntime(3608):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**New Log Cat: This is showing no such table qt_um_stock_items_qty but i have this table in my database and i can access it using my db browser as well**

10-17 06:38:01.523: E/SQLiteLog(4107): (1) no such table: qt_um_stock_items_qty
10-17 06:38:01.523: D/AndroidRuntime(4107): Shutting down VM
10-17 06:38:01.523: W/dalvikvm(4107): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: qt_um_stock_items_qty (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT BAL_DATE AS ON_DT,  (IFNULL ( IN_QTY, 0)-IFNULL (OUT_QTY, 0)) AS CL_QTY,(SELECT CODE || '-' || NAME FROM qm_um_stock_items WHERE ID = STOCK_ITEM_ID) AS ITEM,(SELECT CODE|| '-' ||NAME FROM qm_um_unit WHERE ID = BASE_UNIT_ID ) AS UNIT FROM qt_um_stock_items_qty WHERE STOCK_CENTER_ID =? AND STOCK_ITEM_ID=?
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at com.manacle.umma.activity.HeaderDb.getStockbal(HeaderDb.java:3901)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at com.manacle.umma.activity.StockBalrep$4.onClick(StockBalrep.java:185)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-17 06:38:01.574: E/AndroidRuntime(4107):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please post full exception

Comment: can you post the string  out of this query? so its easier to read

Comment: Yesterday you had another exception, is the query still the same?

Answer (score 1):

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT BAL_DATE AS_ON_DT,  (IFNULL ( IN_QTY, 0)-IFNULL (OUT_QTY, 0)) AS CL_QTY,(SELECT CODE || '-' || NAME FROM qm_um_stock_items WHERE ID = STOCK_ITEM_ID) AS ITEM,(SELECT CODE|| '-' ||NAME FROM qm_um_unit WHERE ID = BASE_UNIT_ID ) AS UNIT FROM Qt_um_stock_items_qty WHERE STOCK_CENTER_ID =? AND STOCK_ITEM_ID IN (=?)
```

The code you posted does not seem to producing exactly this query string. However, the last part

```
AND STOCK_ITEM_ID IN (=?)
```

should probably be either

```
AND STOCK_ITEM_ID =?
```

or something like

```
"AND STOCK_ITEM_ID IN (" + list + ")"
```

where `list` is a comma-separated list of ids (you can use `TextUtils.join()` for that).

Comment: Hi, i got that but this is the error i was talkin about.. Check the logcat